# Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray in Android(repost)

Tags: java, android, database, json

I am repost this coz I dont find the solution for this problem...

here is error

```
org.json.JSONException:Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

here is JSON output:

```
[{"name":"Muhaimin","address":"Sylhet","bgroup":"o+"}]
```

here is class code:

```
entpackage com.example.blood;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView resultView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
StrictMode.enableDefaults();
resultView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
getData();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

public void getData()
{
 String result="";
 InputStream isr=null;
 try{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/blood/index.php");
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
     httppost.setHeader("Accept", "JSON");
    HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
    isr=entity.getContent();
  }catch(Exception e){
    String err=e.toString();
    resultView.setText("Could not connect to database"+err);
    Log.e("error", err);
  }

try{
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    String line=null;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    isr.close();

    result=sb.toString();
   }catch(Exception e){
    String err2=e.toString();
    resultView.setText("Error coverting result"+err2);
    Log.e("error", err2);
  }
  try{
    String s="";
    JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(result);

    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject json=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        s= s + 
                "Name :"+json.getString("name")+"\n"+
                "Blood Group :"+json.getString("bgroup")+"\n" +
                "Address :"+json.getString("address")+"\n\n";
    }
    resultView.setText(s);
  }catch(Exception e){
    String err1=e.toString();
    resultView.setText("xxx"+err1);
    Log.e("error", err1);
 }
 }

}
```

here is php code:

```
  <?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","BloodDB");
mysql_select_db("BloodDB",$con);

$result=mysql_query("SELECT name,address,bgroup FROM tbl_blood_donor");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $output[]=$row;
}
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

Now how to solve this problem.I am working in localhost.thanks in advance

Comment: Exception message and given Json string does not match. Post the actual JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not in JSON and not in the JSONArray so if you got this exception then this means the string to JSONArray not as you expected.
Print the string result and the string length before this line "JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(result);". You can use the below print message for that
Log.d("My String", "string result :[" + result + "] and its length is :" + result.length());

Note that, I used the below code and it working fine

```
String str = "[{\"name\":\"Muhaimin\",\"address\":\"Sylhet\",\"bgroup\":\"o+\"}]";
    try {
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(str);
        Log.d(TAG, "Json value :" + json);
        Log.d(TAG, "Json value :" +    json.getJSONObject(0).getString("bgroup"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

result:
Json value :[{"bgroup":"o+","address":"Sylhet","name":"Muhaimin"}]

Json value :o+

Comment: I use your code and work 

    String str = "[{\"name\":\"Muhaimin\",\"address\":\"Sylhet\",\"bgroup\":\"o+\"}]";
    try {
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(str);
        Log.d(TAG, "Json value :" + json);
        Log.d(TAG, "Json value :" +    json.getJSONObject(0).getString("bgroup"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

but how can i get [{\"name\":\"Muhaimin\",\"address\":\"Sylhet\",\"bgroup\":\"o+\"}] this type json string using php

Comment: If the json will be like in this sample code, it will work but it seams the result which reach to this line JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(result) is not as you expected. Kindly just print the result directly before this line.

Comment: Now show this error

'02-10 05:39:44.850: D/My String(889): <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
02-10 05:39:44.850: D/My String(889): <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
02-10 05:39:44.850: D/My String(889): <BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>
02-10 05:39:44.850: D/My String(889): <hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>
02-10 05:39:44.850: D/My String(889): </BODY></HTML>
02-10 05:39:44.850: D/My String(889): ] and its length is :309
'

Comment: Good, now we know what you got this exception. You got it because when you made post request to the mentioned URL in your code, the request failed and return 404.
You need to make the following:
1- First check on the return status from your http post method and handle the failure case. You can use those methods for that response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase()
HttpStatus.SC_OK to compare with it
2- You need to check your environment to know why you cannot access this url http://10.0.2.2/blood/index.php and if it is post or get method

Comment: I tried this in my code Log.d("My String", "string result :[" + result + "] and its length is :" + result.length()); But it has no printout, anyone able to tell me why ? and I seem to have a JSON Object error after that upon creation as I try to put result into it.