# Jsonexception while accessing data from 000webhost

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql-server, json

I'm fetching data from a table from php server(000webhost) and displaying it in a list view. I following this link to accomplish this :

> http://codeoncloud.blogspot.com/2013/07/android-mysql-php-json-tutorial.html

For me it's working absolutely right but when I send .apk file to my friend in another country, he's receiving following error :

> doctype of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonobject

this error is discussed in many links included

> [org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876079/org-json-jsonexception-value-doctype-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-conve)
>   [Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray in Android(repost)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674326/value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonarray-in-androidrepos)

But my problem is that same code is working fine for me. That's why I could not test even that where problem is occurring. If anyone else have faced same issue. please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible that what url you are using for getting json response in your mobile that url is not working in his mobile means that url may be restricted in his mobile.

Comment: I'll ask him to test URL. Thanks :)